# Change Atom Keybinding Source

Tags: javascript, atom-editor, nuclide-editor

Currently the key binding I have Ctrl-Shift-C does code formatting but after a key inspection its using Atom Ide Code Format instead of nuclide-js-format (the desired installed package). How can I change the source to only use the formatter from the desired package?

Currently my keymap.cson looks like this:

```
'.platform-linux atom-workspace atom-text-editor:not(.mini)':
  'ctrl-shift-C': 'code-format:format-code'
```